# Observables are reacting very slowly in Angular Application

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

The problem: 
When I receive an observable it takes 2-10 seconds to update a corresponding UI-Element.

What I do to get there:

1. I get a QR-Code from an API.
2. I do some funny backend stuff and connect to a WebRTC-Connection.
3. As the connection is opened I set an observable to .next(true).
4. Now it takes some time, 2-10 seconds,
5. then the UI updates (the update is, making the QR-Code invisible).

Code:

```
project.json
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^13.0.0-beta.36",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.4.0",
    "socket.io-client": "2.4",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.4.3"
  }
}
```

```
tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom"
    ],

  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  }
}
```

```
QrCodeComponent.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'qrcode-element',
  templateUrl: './qr-code.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./qr-code.component.css']
})

export class QrCodeComponent implements OnInit {
  qrCode$: Observable<IQrCode>;
  isUpdating$: Observable<boolean>;
  showQrCode$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private qrcodeFacade: QrcodeFacade, private webRtcConnectionFacade:WebRtcConnectionFacade) {
    this.qrCode$ = qrcodeFacade.getQrCode();
    this.isUpdating$ = qrcodeFacade.isUpdating();
    this.showQrCode$ = webRtcConnectionFacade.getDataChannelState();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.qrcodeFacade.loadQrCode();
  }
```

```
QrcodeFacade.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class QrcodeFacade {

  constructor(private qrCodeApi: QrCodeApi, private qrcodeState: QrcodeState) { }

  isUpdating(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.qrcodeState.isUpdating();
  }

  getQrCode(): Observable<IQrCode> {
    return this.qrcodeState.getQrCode();
  }
}
```

```
QrcodeState.ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'any'
})
export class QrcodeState {
  private updating = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private qrCode = new BehaviorSubject<IQrCode>(emptyQrCode());

  constructor(private socketClient: SocketClient, private webRtcConnectionService: WebRtcConnectionService) {
  }

  isUpdating() {
    return this.updating.asObservable();
  }

  setUpdating(isUpdating: boolean) {
    this.updating.next(isUpdating);
  }

  getQrCode() {
    return this.qrCode.asObservable();
  }
```

Please let me know if you need any other code.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please try to make your question shorter with the relevant code. Question should be a question like `Why does my UI takes several seconds to update after an observable value is emitted?`. The libraries/tsconfig is 'à priori' not needed. On the other hand, the way your bind the observable values in your html template would be useful.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).